# Solving system of equation modulo 2

Tags: c++, vector

I make a program in C++, that factorizes natural numbers. The only problem is to create a function that does the following:

1. input: it receives a matrix  `vector< vector< int> > M`.
2. output: it gives a `vector v` so that a result of multiplying v and M is a vector that all its coordinates are equal to 0.

Everything must be modulo 2, so coefficients of M and v consists only 0s and 1s

Schould I use a Gauss elimination method? If so, how do this? The problem that implementations I saw on the net don't use vectors and the vectors are necessary in my main program

I would be grateful if someone helped me.

Regards

Comment: nobody uses matrices of type `vector<vector>` because that's terribly inefficient. Use some code from the net and if necessary then simply convert the vectors.

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: `v` consisting of all zeros appears to satisfy the requirements - multiplying it by any matrix produces a vector of all zeros.

Answer (score 2):

This is an interesting problem. The steps to be taken can be found in this exercise. [link](https://faculty.uml.edu/klevasseur/ads/s-systems-linear-equations-mod-2.html).

The tricky part is to understand that there are always only a finite number of solutions, i.e, only the trivial solution exists or non-trivial solutions exist.

Once you finish the row reduction steps and if non-trivial solutions exist, there is always going to be at least one independent variable (it can take any value 0/1) and the rest of the variables depend on the independent variables.

Comment: Just to clarify, in the above [link](https://faculty.uml.edu/klevasseur/ads/s-systems-linear-equations-mod-2.html), in the explained example, x3,x5,x6 are independent variables. Variables that have no row making them basic are what I am calling independent variables.